# getting error in bitbake gstreamer1.0-plugins-good

Tags: linux, gstreamer, yocto, pulseaudio, yocto-recipe

```
ERROR: pulseaudio-10.0-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: pulseaudio-10.0-r0 do_compile: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/user/user_work/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/pulseaudio/10.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.11766)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/user/user_work/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/pulseaudio/10.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.11766
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: SITE files ['endian-little', 'bit-64', 'arm-common', 'arm-64', 'common-linux', 'common-glibc', 'aarch64-linux', 'common']
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| NOTE: make -j 5
| make  all-recursive
| make[1]: Entering directory '/home/user/user_work/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/pulseaudio/10.0-r0/build'
| Making all in src
| make[2]: Entering directory '/home/user/user_work/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/pulseaudio/10.0-r0/build/src'
| /home/user/user_work/build/tmp/hosttools/mkdir -p daemon modules
| make  all-am
| make[3]: Entering directory '/home/user/user_work/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/pulseaudio/10.0-r0/build/src'



pulseaudio_10.0.bb:do_compile failed with exit code '1'
```

Comment: This error message is not complete and it is not useful to help you, you should identify the actual error message, from the compiler or other, and include it in your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: do not tag this "computer vision" when it is not.